# In MSAGL how to specify the layout direction for Sugiyama layout option?

Tags: c#, winforms, msagl

By default, MSAGL graph library displays the Sugiyama layout which renders nodes from top to bottom, vertically . I need the graph to be rendered horizontally instead of vertically? How can this be achieved? I could not find a setting which allows me to specify the direction of the generated graph.

Any help or pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Got the solution:

Need to add the below code to set the direction.

```
            graph.Attr.LayerDirection = LayerDirection.LR;
```